# How to detect if image contains ASCII characters?

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a dataset of images and I want to filter out all images that contain text (ASCII chars). For example, I have the following cute image of a dog:

[image]

As you can see, on right bottom corner there is a text "MAY 18 2003" so it should be filtered out.

After some research, I came across with `tesseract` OCR. In python I have the following code:

```
# Attempt 1
img = Image.open('n02086240_1681.jpg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)

# Attempt 2
import unidecode
img = Image.open('n02086240_1681.jpg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
text = unidecode.unidecode(text)
print(text)

# Attempt 3
import string
char_whitelist = string.digits
char_whitelist += string.ascii_lowercase
char_whitelist += string.ascii_uppercase
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang='eng',
                        config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
print(text)
```

None of them detected the string (prints whitespaces). How can I detect it?

Comment: @vessi if you want to use `tesseract` please see this tutorial on how to [improve the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html) but this process might vary among the images of your dataset, to "*filter out all images that contain text (ASCII chars)*" with reasonable results for a huge dataset you might use Deep-Learning, binary classification in particular to classify the images that contain ASCII characters in order to exclude them.

Comment: @vessi plus this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70695024) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

you should prepare the image for the OCR.

for example, for this image I would do the following:

1. convert it to Black & White image with threshold that make the text visible (for this image it is 130)
   [image]
2. then I would Invert the image (so the text be in black)
   [image]
3. now try tesseract OCR

Comment: Can you please paste the code you did for those two steps?

Comment: please read this https://nanonets.com/blog/ocr-with-tesseract/ it will help

Comment: @Jabbar I have downloaded the processed image from your answer, and tried `tesseract`, it turns that it didn't work!

Comment: use `Page layout analysis - split multi-column text into columns` or `Automatic page segmentation` with tesseract, you can test it here https://www.newocr.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Easy-OCR](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR) instead of `pytesseract` to get directly this output

> Kay
> 10   2003

and as your goal is just to detect ASCII, you don't care about the accurate characters because you just want to filter the images which contain them.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cv2
import easyocr

path = ""
img = cv2.imread(path+"input.jpg")

# Now apply the Easy-OCR
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])

output = reader.readtext(img)

for i in range(len(output)):
    print(output[i][-2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [inRange thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html)

The result will be:

[image]

If you set `psm` mode to the 6, the output will be:

```
<<
‘\
' MAY 18 2003
```

All the digits are captured correctly, but we have some unwanted characters.
If we add an ['only-alpha numeric'](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-isalpha-isnumeric-isalnum/) condition, then the result will be:

```
['M', 'A', 'Y', '1', '8', '2', '0', '0', '3']
```

First, I've upsampled the image, and then apply tesseract-OCR. The reason is that the date is too small to read.

Code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
from numpy import array

img = cv2.imread("result.png")  # Load the upsampled image
img = cv2.cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
msk = cv2.inRange(img, array([0, 103, 171]), array([179, 255, 255]))
krn = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3))
dlt = cv2.dilate(msk, krn, iterations=1)
thr = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(dlt, msk)

txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config='--psm 6')
print([t for t in txt if t.isalnum()])
cv2.imshow("", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You can set the new values for the minimum and maximum ranges:

```py
import numpy as np

min_range = np.array([0, 103, 171])
max_range = np.array([179, 255, 255])
msk = cv2.inRange(img, min_range, max_range)
```

You can also test with different `psm` parameters:

```py
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config='--psm 6')
```

For more read: [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)