# Text extraction from the images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, text-extraction

I need to extract characters from the images, but the images are varying a lot because of surrounding light effect. because of this I am not able to fix any particular pre-processing method.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

my pre-processing code looks as below:

```
from skimage import io
import cv2
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu, sobel
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

image = io.imread(imgg)
dim = (700, 100)   #76 pixels
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

image = rgb2gray(resized_image)
threshold = threshold_otsu(image)
bina_image = image < threshold

img = img_as_ubyte(bina_image )
image_copy = img.copy()
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=5.0, tileGridSize=(1,1))
img[:,:,0] = clahe.apply(img[:,:,0])

imghsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
imghsv[:,:,2] = [[max(pixel - 25, 0) if pixel < 190 else min(pixel + 25, 255) for pixel in row] for row in imghsv[:,:,2]]
imghsv[imghsv < 170] = 0
imghsv[imghsv > 170] = 255
```

I have tried ocrs like tesseract, EasyOCR and KerasOCR but none of them worked for this case.
can you please suggest how can I get all the characters from these kind of images?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post an actual [mre], including all necessary imports. Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect. We should be able to paste a single block of your code into a file, run it, and reproduce your problem. This also lets us test any possible solutions in your context.

Comment: pictures look familiar. what happened to the previous question? -- applying CLAHE **after you've already thresholded it** is pointless IMHO, because there is no way to "enhance contrast" in a *binary* image. I hope I'm just reading your code wrong. -- CLAHE is probably useful here, but *before* you threshold.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) will help you

Comment: @ChetuJadar you can use `EasyOCR` similarly to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70734641)

Comment: You can use OpenCV Inference Engine API, which has very useful models to do different recognition and text extraction, and so on.

Comment: @MattDMo , Thanks for bringing that to my notice. Now i have added all the necessary imports.

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege , Bilal I tried OCRs but didnt work for case, Now i have edited that sentence in my post.

Comment: Try rotating the images so the text is horizontal. Then try some of the different options in tesseract.

Comment: @fmw42 , Yes I tried to rotate, deskewing methods but i am not able get some characters like alphanumeric characters (For ex: 6 is identified as "G", "A" as 4, 8 as "B" etc)

Comment: Did you rotate the whole image or each letter?

Comment: i rotated the whole image

Answer (score 0):

Text binarization represents a complicated task under varying illumination and noise. Factors such as the variance of gray levels, brightness, and backgrounds complicate the thresholding scheme. If you have enough resources, I recommend you [google cloud vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#vision_text_detection_gcs-python)

The code to implement it is easy to understand:

```
def detect_text_uri(uri):
"""Detects text in the file located in Google Cloud Storage or on the Web.
"""
from google.cloud import vision
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
image = vision.Image()
image.source.image_uri = uri

response = client.text_detection(image=image)
texts = response.text_annotations
print('Texts:')

for text in texts:
    print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description))

    vertices = (['({},{})'.format(vertex.x, vertex.y)
                for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices])

    print('bounds: {}'.format(','.join(vertices)))

if response.error.message:
    raise Exception(
        '{}\nFor more info on error messages, check: '
        'https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors'.format(
            response.error.message))
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but Google is a paid API so could not proceed with this.

Comment: It is cheap and you can start for free. You will save a lot of time